# Magento Checkout Cart Image Thumbnail Resize White Frame/Border

Tags: cart, image, thumbnail

In my checkout cart there is a white frame/border/background around my actual product image. it is because the image is not in the format 1:1

now my problem is, how to get rid of the white frame/border around the actual product image.

I am using Magento 1.8.0.0

I tried changing my code in checkout/cart/item/default.phtml like this:

From:

```
$this->getProductThumbnail()->resize(265);
```

To:

```
$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail',
 $_image->getFile())->keepFrame(false)->resize(100);
```

Now when I do this the cart does not work anymore

I really need help

Comment: `$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail',
 $_image->getFile())->keepAspectRatio(flase)->keepFrame(false)->resize(100);` perhaps? Note the keepAspectRatio.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

> $this->getProductThumbnail()->resize(265);

to

> $this->getProductThumbnail()->keepFrame(false)->resize(265);

Comment: thank you! sadly this did not help. now the cart does not show any items