# How rezise the thumbnails image in magento 1?

Tags: magento-1.9, thumbnail

The magento thumbnails from the products are wrong format. **(square)**

I want all the pictures an other format  2/3.

How or where can i change this to get effect?

Comment: probably a duplicate of http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/17912/magento-checkout-cart-image-thumbnail-resize-white-frame-border

Answer (score 2):

The method Magento uses to generate thumbnails (of any size) is `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image::resize()`:

```
/**
 * Schedule resize of the image
 * $width *or* $height can be null - in this case, lacking dimension will be calculated.
 *
 * @see Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Image
 * @param int $width
 * @param int $height
 * @return Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image
 */
public function resize($width, $height = null)
{
    $this->_getModel()->setWidth($width)->setHeight($height);
    $this->_scheduleResize = true;
    return $this;
}
```

Unfortunately the parameters are hard coded all over the place, at least in the default theme. Search in your theme (`app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme`) for `resize(` and change the parameters accordingly.

Comment: thanks, hard to find for a starter with so much files. What is the best way to search in all that files on the word resize?

Comment: That's a matter of taste. If you use an IDE like Eclipse or PHPStorm, you can use its "search in files" feature. Notepad++ has a good file search dialog too. Or you can use `grep` on the command line.