# Allow SVG on Product images

Tags: magento-1.8, product-attribute, image, image-upload

[image]

How do I allow this attribute type to handle SVG?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As others have pointed out, the allowed image extensions are hard coded in core files. However, I found an observer that allows you to change them along with other configuration of the uploader:

**This goes into your config.xml**

```
<config>
    <adminhtml>
        <events>
            <catalog_product_gallery_prepare_layout>
                <observers>
                    <your_module>
                        <class>your_module/observer</class>
                        <method>setFlexUploaderConfig</method>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                    </your_module>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_gallery_prepare_layout>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

**This is your observer**

```
class Your_Module_Model_Observer
{
    /**
     * Adds file types to allowed file types of file selector
     *
     * @see event catalog_product_gallery_prepare_layout
     * @see block Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Helper_Form_Gallery_Content
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     */
    public function setFlexUploaderConfig(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        /* @var $galleryBlock Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Helper_Form_Gallery_Content */
        $uploaderConfig = $observer->getBlock()->getUploader()->getConfig();
        $additionalExtensions = array('*.svg');
        $uploaderFileFilters = $uploaderConfig->getFilters();
        $uploaderFileFilters['vector_images'] = array(
                'label' => $this->__('Vector Images') . ' (' . join(', ', $additionalExtensions) . ')',
                'files' => $additionalExtensions
        );
        $uploaderConfig->setFilters($uploaderFileFilters);
    }
}
```

You can change the existing filter `images` instead of adding a new one as well, I just took the code from a module where I allowed video uploads, so an additional filter made sense. The filters define the dropdowns in the "open file" dialog.

For the server side validation you still need to override the gallery upload action:

**config.xml**

```
<config>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Your_Module before="Mage_Adminhtml">Your_Module_Adminhtml</Your_Module>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

**Your controller:**

```
class Your_Module_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_GalleryController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_GalleryController
{
    public static $allowedImageExtensions = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png');
    public static $allowedVectorExtensions = array('svg');

    /**
     * Overridden to reconfigure the Uploader
     *
     * (non-PHPdoc)
     * @see Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_GalleryController::uploadAction()
     */
    public function uploadAction()
    {
        try {
            $uploader = new Mage_Core_Model_File_Uploader('image');


            // BEGIN change
            $uploader->setAllowedExtensions($this->_getAllowedExtensions());
            $uploader->addValidateCallback('catalog_product_image', $this, 'validateUploadImage');
            $uploader->addValidateCallback('svg_image', $this, 'validateUploadVector');
            // END change


            $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
            $uploader->setFilesDispersion(true);
            $result = $uploader->save(
                Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_media_config')->getBaseTmpMediaPath()
            );

            Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_product_gallery_upload_image_after', array(
                'result' => $result,
                'action' => $this
            ));

            /**
             * Workaround for prototype 1.7 methods "isJSON", "evalJSON" on Windows OS
             */
            $result['tmp_name'] = str_replace(DS, "/", $result['tmp_name']);
            $result['path'] = str_replace(DS, "/", $result['path']);

            $result['url'] = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_media_config')->getTmpMediaUrl($result['file']);
            $result['file'] = $result['file'] . '.tmp';
            $result['cookie'] = array(
                'name'     => session_name(),
                'value'    => $this->_getSession()->getSessionId(),
                'lifetime' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieLifetime(),
                'path'     => $this->_getSession()->getCookiePath(),
                'domain'   => $this->_getSession()->getCookieDomain()
            );

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $result = array(
                'error' => $e->getMessage(),
                'errorcode' => $e->getCode());
        }

        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
    }

    protected function _getAllowedExtensions()
    {
        return array_merge(self::$allowedImageExtensions, self::$allowedVectorExtensions);
    }
    public function validateUploadImage($file)
    {
        if (in_array(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), self::$allowedImageExtensions)) {
            return Mage::helper('catalog/image')->validateUploadFile($file);
        }
    }
    public function validateUploadVector($file)
    {
        if (in_array(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), self::$allowedVectorExtensions)) {
            //TODO throw exception if invalid file
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

This controller overrides the `uploadAction` of the original gallery controller. You see, that it is necessary to add a second validator and only use the original validator from `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image` if the image has one of the file types supported by [the GD extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/image.constants.php). In the `validateUploadVector` method above you can add additional validation for SVG files and throw an Exception if the file is not a valid SVG.

**Template changes**

Additionally you will need to change your templates to display SVG files correctly, i.e. not using the thumbnail generation methods if the file is an SVG. Alternatively you could try to rewrite `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image::resize()` to ignore SVG files. [See also this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/37811/243)

Answer (score 1):

as far as i know you have to add this file extension in the corresponding file:

> app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category/Attribute/Backend/Image.php

around line 58 you will find:

```
$uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'));
```

add here your new extensions like **svg**

```
$uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png','svg'));
```

But copy this file to:

> app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category/Attribute/Backend/Image.php

Comment: Bad practise to copy full files if there is another way. (not update-safe)

Comment: Correct me if Im wrong @Alex but I think if you move the file to local - it wont be overridden on your next update. 

Considering the amount of time it takes to build out a full controller for such a minor change - this is a quick (and mostly dirty) was of making it happen.

Comment: @Rebel problem is that if in future Magento versions the Image.php is updated, you do not profit from those changes

Answer (score 0):

The allowed image extensions are defined in `Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Backend/Media.php` and `Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/GalleryController.php`

You can override thme and change the function `addImage` for the first and `uploadAction()` for the second.

I tried to see where it can influence but did not find anything yet.