# Magento 1.9.0.1 upload svg files as product image

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, image-upload

I tried the [observer creating method](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/38170/allow-svg-on-product-images) for allow svg upload. It doesn't work for this version(1.9.0.1). I found that allowed image types are hard coded in these files,

`Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Backend/Media.php` 
`Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/GalleryController.php`

I added svg to those files. But still no success. Am I missing something?

Comment: ping for @fschmengler

Comment: My solution contained an override for `GalleryController::uploadAction()`, additionally to the observer. TBH this code is working on Magento 1.8 but I did not yet have the chance to test it on 1.9, if something has changed.

Comment: @fschmengler Yes. Tried the entire solution. But no luck.

Comment: Anyone knows at least a way to change core files?

Comment: May you can use this http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/upload-svg-vector-images-for-products.html

Comment: @StefanGregori Tried that extension. It has same method that  fschmengler explained in his answer. So that also not worked.